# remote long running command

Tags: fabric, paramiko

I have a simple bash script only does “sleep 3600” on remote host (Amazon EC2) and I am using fabric to call it via fabric.operations.run (I did NOT set any env.timeout or env.command_timeout).

If the remote bash script sleeps for 3600 seconds, fabric was NOT able to return after the bash script is done running. I printed the stack trace and it kept waiting on `channel.exits_status_ready()` (https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/operations.py LINE: 794) even if the script already returned.

This ONLY happens for long running process. I tried to make bash script sleep for 120 seconds and it worked fine.

I double checked the open connections using netstat, and the ssh session opened by fabric was still alive.

Help needed :) Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Is your connection just getting dropped by the network?  Is there a timeout on the target host?  Is there a reason you're not running the command with nohup/in a screen session?

Comment: No... I have other connections as well in the meantime.. they weren't timed out.. and I have to use fabric library for this

Comment: In order to avoid problems related to broken network connections, you can run your remote application using some tool as `screen` or `tmux`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out, just needed to use env.keepalive = 1